# Ios - PrepareforSegue between two ViewController but with another Viewcontroller between both

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three ViewController A, B, and C.

I want to pass a data from A to C.
But when user uses my app, he has to pass by B ViewController before C ViewController.
And the segue identifier is between A and B.

ViewController A and C aren't linked in Storyboard. May be it's the problem...

I try this but Xcode doesn't recognize variable ndj2 from ViewController C.

I put the correct #import ViewControllerC.h

I already try to pass date between A and B, and it's working. 
It's to avoid to do two prepareForSegue (one between ViewController A and ViewController B / and another between ViewController B and ViewController C)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   ViewControllerA *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

       NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
       if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"quelnom"]) // identifier between A and B
      {

           transferViewController.ndj2 = ndj;
      // ndj2 is variable present in ViewController C
      }
   };
```

The real problem is ndj2 is non recognize , and i declared it properly. It's the Viewcontroller the problem but i don't understand why...

Comment: You did not tell what exactly does not work. I'm assuming that you did not get any error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you need to look into how to use singleton objects to transfer data between views in a neat way.. for example i use this

for propertyManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PropertyManager : NSObject{

}
+ (PropertyManager*) sharedPropertyManager;


@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* chapterId;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString* chapterName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString * clicked;

@end
```

and for .m file

```
#import "PropertyManager.h"

@implementation PropertyManager
static PropertyManager* _sharedPropertyManager = nil;

+ (PropertyManager*) sharedPropertyManager{
    @synchronized([PropertyManager class]){

        if (!_sharedPropertyManager) {
            [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return _sharedPropertyManager;
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (id) alloc{
    @synchronized([PropertyManager class]){
        NSAssert(_sharedPropertyManager==nil,@"Attempted to allocate a second instance of the PropertyManager");
        _sharedPropertyManager = [super alloc];
        return _sharedPropertyManager;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id) init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Singleton PropertyManager is Running");

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

when you need to put data from view to view you simply use

```
[[PropertyManager sharedPropertyManager]setChapterId:"1"];
```

and get it in any other view by

```
[[PropertyManager sharedPropertyManager]chapterId];
```

Answer (score 0):

in C ViewController you ndj2 initialized as `@property` 
 and **ViewControllerC *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
       NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
       if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"quelnom"]) // identifier between A and B
      {
           ViewControllerC *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
           transferViewController.ndj2 = ndj;
      // ndj2 is variable present in ViewController C
      }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ndj2` is declared as a property in both `ViewControllerB` and `ViewControllerC`, and these two ViewControllers are also connected by a segue, then you just need to initialize `ViewControllerC.ndj2` in `prepareForSegue` method of ViewControllerB just like you did in `ViewControllerA`.

Now you initialize only `ViewControllerB.ndj2`, but it is not passed to `ViewControllerC` automatically.